# How to backup data from Gitbook?

Tags: backup, gitbook

Me and my organisation are using gitbook a lot for documentation.
We have a lot of stuff in there, and we are worried to loose it.
I can't figure out how to make even just a manual backup of the data on gitbook, someone has experience with that ? I'd just like to have a local save from time to time.

https://ss3d.gitbook.io/home/

I looked on gitbook official website and could not find any doc regarding backing it up.

https://www.gitbook.com/